# Sencha Touch how to set selected item in selectfield

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm using Sencha Touch 2.3.1.
How to set an select item in a selectfield ? It's seem no method to support this. I don't want do the trick set an Placeholder to the selectfield.

I have tried to Google it. But it's seem nobody talk about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously it supports.

The value of the `Ext.field.Select` itself is the value of the selected item. So, you can either set the initial value or dynamically change it at anytime with the `value` config, via `setValue` method.

Comment: Oh thanks so much ! I realized that i unchecked the autoSelect so that the setValue()/many try didn't work for me.